# Whats the cheapest particles to use? Both in Blender Render and Cycles

Tags: particles

So, if I want to use an insane amount of particles, what is the cheapest render setup? In PCU usage? 
In Unreal Engine the sprite particles (billboard) are very cheap to use, but can be set to use GPU instead of CPU. 
In Blender, will they be much cheaper to use on a CPU than low poly mesh objects? 
Would a plane with texture and alpha work just as well, for use in cycles for example?
Can I use the GPU for the billboard particles in Blender?

Would love to get some more information on this. Could not find the answer anywhere.

Comment: There is the general notion of ... Near Photo Realistic NPR rendering requires more compute time either on CPU or GPU.  Simply speaking Cycles is certainly more intended and recognized for NPR then Blender Internal Render.  This might imply Cycles renderings take more time if NPR is the goal.  The above comment is worthwhile.  You might want to give a specific number rather than the [insane] description.    Of course  we want to avoid a hardware description here.  You might specifiy the tests you have completed already.

Comment: I dont really have any specific project im working on for this question. I have been trying to figure out whats fast to work with, and if sprite based particles would give me any bonus in computing time. But i might have asked the question poorly. Lets say I make sparks in Blender Internal, and use one hundred thousand particles. Would it be cheaper to use billboard particles than object based particles? Would it be a big difference? Is mesh harder on the CPU?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing to do is to benchmark. My five cents are that (personal best guess based on seven years of Blender usage, but not backed by actual tests):

- If you are only rendering the particles (black or photographic background), you can get away by using only one (or 2 for antialias) sample in Cycles. It should be fast.
- If you have something else Cycles-powered in the scene, you would have to crank up the samples, thus rendering bounces from  the particles. That could be a real pain. You may want to do a mixed composite.
- If you are doing it in the internal in the first place, stick with it.

Using the "Halo" setting (in the internal) could give more pleasant results than "Billboard" if you are doing sparks or somesuch.

Cycleswise you could give a shot at the new point density input for a volume. It has the good side of not requiring you to make physical planes orient themselves to the camera. I am pretty sure it is far slower than anything else though.

Comment: I guess billboard and halo is easier to render than objects because they dont need to calculate bouncing?

Comment: True, plus they are slightly easier to set up. [Brought to you by: the laziest man to ever walk this earth.]

Comment: Hahah :) well, easy setup in Blender means more time for pumping weights in your spare time!